# change image and text color when I hover any one of them

Tags: html, css, hover

I have an image and a text next to it (put in a list, each in a li) and what I want to do is when I hover ANY of them, the image changes to another, and the text changes color.

Here is my code:

```
<ul id="recherche">
    <li><a href="#"><img id="glo" src="images/glosaire_off.png" alt=""/></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is the hover that I want to do for the image change:

```
#glo:hover{
    background-image:url(../images/glosaire_on.png) ;
}
```

So does anyone know how to apply a hover effect on both things, as soon as we hover any one of them? Thanks!

Comment: Changing the `background-image` of an `img` element won't display a new image if the `src` attribute is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image set using `src` attribute of `img` tag will overlap the image set using `background-image` style. What you need to be doing is this:
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LM4dP/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="recherche">
            <li><a href="#"><img id="glo" src="#" alt=""/></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul:hover #glo{
    background-image:url(../images/glosaire_on.jpg) ;
}
ul:hover a{ color: teal;}

ul #glo{
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image:url(../images/glosaire_off.jpg) ;
}
ul a{ color: green;}
```

Also, you'll need to mention the `width` & `height` for the `img` element.

---

**EDIT:**

In order to apply hover to sets of 2 `li` elements in tandem, you will need to encapsulate them in their individual `ul` element as follows:

```
<ul id="recherche">
    <li id="glo"><a href="#"></br></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li id="rech"><a href="#"></br></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Recherche</a></li>
</ul>
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/LM4dP/3/)

*Also, check out the CSS change needed to ensure right elements are targetted.*
**CSS:**

```
ul {
    width: 300px;
}
ul:hover li:first-child {
    background-image:url(http://mailboxtolucalake.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-2.jpg);
}
ul:hover li:first-child + li a {
    color: teal;
}
ul li:first-child {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image:url(http://mailboxtolucalake.com/wp-content/themes/thesis/rotator/sample-1.jpg);
}
ul li:first-child + li a {
    color: green;
}
```

I've used `first-child` selector and sibling selector of CSS (`+`) to target appropriate elements.

Comment: your solution worked perfectly, thanks. But there is still one little issue, it's that I have more than those two elements in my list, which causes that all my elements are getting affected by my hover. here is my entire code:
`<ul id="recherche">
                <li id="glo"><a href="#"></br></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
                <li id="rech"><a href="#"></br></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Recherche</a></li>
        </ul>`
I want to apply hover on the first two 'li's together,and the other two seperately.Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: The only solution to this is encapsulating the related `li` elements in their individual `ul` element like: `<ul><li id='glo'></li><li></li></ul><ul><li id='rech'></li><li></li></ul>` Take a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this two ways !

I would prefer using a `class=""` selector !

**WARNING:** You set the attribute `src:` but you attempt at changing the `background-image:`

lets says that

```
<ul id="recherche">
            <li><a href="#" class="glow"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="glow" style="background-image:none">Glossaire</a></li>
</ul>
```

You do the inline one because you dont want the b`ackground-image` to be applied to the second anchor tag

now the CSS:

```
.glow{
background-image:url('/*some url*/');/*the default one*/
}


.glow:hover{
background-image:url('')/*New url inside*/
color:/*some color here, this helps with the text color*/;
}
```

Comment: although in this case with the given code, you don't need to add the extra glo(glow in css) class

Comment: Sorry about that, i was just encouraging him to use a `class` selector when attempting to apply a style to multiple elements.

Comment: @TJonS A class isn't needed here but he used class instead of id because class is made to apply to multiple elements where id is made to apply to 1 unique element

Comment: I dont think I would go in for **debate** for this.
I use it like this,

*If I want to style a particular element, I use `id` else I would go for a `class` selector when attempting to apply a style to many elements.

Comment: you might want to correct the glo vs glow in your html and css

Comment: @TJonS Main reason to use classes is that you can have multiple elements with the same class. I don't see any issue with using ID selectors for this example.

Comment: @ Huangism : Thanks dude. I just interpreted it as **glow** for css,while I just edited his code for HTML.My bad, sorry !

Comment: Wouldn't this example apply the `background-image` to the "Glossaire" LI element as well? It doesn't look like this is what the OP wanted, they wanted to just change the text color of the second LI.

Comment: He can override the CSS with inline set to `<a href="#" style="background-image:none">Glossaire</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#recherche:hover #glo{
    background-image:url(../images/glosaire_on.png) ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is answer

```
 li:hover {
        background-image:url(../images/glosaire_on.png) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#recherche li a:hover{ background:url(../images/glosaire_on.png)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with you have `glosaire_off.png` on mark up and your are trying to apply a background image on hover using CSS.  Surely, you want to change the img src to g`losaire_on.png` when on hover and change the text colour? if that's the case you will have to use JavaScript to do this.

**EDIT**

**Assuming you have jQuery**

```
<ul id="recherche">
    <li><a href="#"><img id="glo" src="images/glosaire_off.png"/>Some text</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Glossaire</a></li>
</ul>

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#glo").mouseenter(function(){
       $(this).attr("src","images/glosaire_off.png");
       $(this).parent().css("color", "green"); 
    }).mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).attr("src","images/glosaire_on.png");
       $(this).parent().css("color", "red");        
    });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5jxFu/)